# Fan keeps running! Dell Inspiron N7010

Tags: laptop, fan, dell-inspiron

I keep upgrading my laptop and still the fan continues to run ridiculously too loud and too often. It's a Dell Inspiron N7010, I upgraded the HDD to SSD, added 8 GB's of RAM, installed a new faster, compatible processor (i5 instead of i3), installed a NEW fan all together yesterday along with new Heatsink. Still the fan keeps running annoying as hell! Any idea what I could be missing? No BIOS updates needed, I also run Driver Scanner and Registry/drive cleaners consistently..

Comment: to be honest, you should upgrade from a laptop to a desktop if you want to deal with persistent thermal issues. none of your upgrades would have reduced your heat much, if at all (in fact i5's run hotter than i3's, and more ram is more heat) other than replacing the fan, and then only if the old fan was mechanically damaged. Personally I'd rather be in your position than the one I have with my HP, which won't kick up the fans until its at 70C and already bogging down.

Comment: With all the upgrades you listed, you've added heat to the system area. That likely why the fan is running so hard. Unless you can access the control of the fan, it is likely doing what it's supposed to do.

Comment: I used Speefan to reduce the speed of my cpu fan: http://www.almico.com/sfarticle.php?id=5

Comment: Is there a cooling stand available for your laptop?  I would try that or heed @FrankThomas advice.

Comment: have you monitored the CPU usage of the system - maybe there is something (eg web browser) which is chewing up the available CPU cycles - regardless of how many you throw at it - and generating heat?

Comment: The laptop most likely wasn't designed to be upgraded so much so the fan is doing its best to cool down everything. There are programs that control your fans, you'd have to research.